# Oracle, can't access to tablespace by user

Tags: oracle, tablespace

I use Enterprise Manager Database Express 18.3.0.0.0 
And
I use SQL DEVELOPER 18.4.0.376

OS: Windows 10

I have to execute some sql like this to create a table:

```
 CREATE TABLE "MYDATABASE"."MYCUSTOMTABLE" 
   (    "ID" VARCHAR2(36 BYTE), 
    "FILE_DATA" BLOB, 
    "TAGFR" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "TATO" NUMBER(*,0), 
    "FLAG" NUMBER(*,0)
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 202144 NEXT 1548576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2047486543
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "MYTABLESPACE_DATA" 
 LOB ("FILE_DATA") STORE AS BASICFILE (
  TABLESPACE "MYTABLESPACE_DATA" ENABLE STORAGE IN ROW CHUNK 32768 PCTVERSION 20
  CACHE 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1548576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2047486543
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)) ;
```

But i got this error:

```
Report error -
ORA-01950: no privileges on tablespace 'MYTABLESPACE_DATA'
01950. 00000 -  "no privileges on tablespace '%s'"
*Cause:    User does not have privileges to allocate an extent in the
           specified tablespace.
*Action:   Grant the user the appropriate system privileges or grant the user
           space resource on the tablespace.
```

I execute this line sql:

```
GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO MYUSER
```

The default tablespace of MYUSER is MYTABLESPACE_DATA.

I continue to have the same error, what am I wrong? What am I not doing?

Comment: possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27940522/no-privileges-on-tablespace-users

Comment: Are `MYUSER` and `MYDATABASE` the same thing really? If not you need to grant the privilege - or preferably a quota on that tablespace - to `MYDATABASE` as the table owner. If they are the same, did the grant (as a privileged user e.g. SYS) work; and has `MYUSER`/`MYDATABASE` reconnected since that grant was made? (I can't remember if you need to for that one to take effect...)

Comment: It seems I solved the problem somehow, I closed and reopened Sql Developer and the table was created.

Comment: Right, because by doing that you reconnected - and your new session picked up the newly-granted privilege.